# Find all prime ideals that include the ideal $(xz)$ and are not maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A＝\mathbb Q[x,y,z]/(x^2y^2-z^3)$. I want to find all prime but not maximal ideals that include the ideal $(xz)$ in $A$.

I found $(x,z)⊃(xz)$ is the ideal which satisfies the condition. But I cannot find other ideals.

I want to find all of ideals, thank you.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799638/is-x2y2-z3-irreducible-element-in-qx-y-z).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In effect you are seeking prime ideals containing $I=(xz,x^2y^2-z^3)$ in $R=\Bbb Q[x,y,z]$.
If $I\subseteq P$, a prime ideal, then $xz\in P$ so either $x\in P$ or $z\in P$.

If $x\in P$ then $P\supseteq(x,xz,x^2y^2-z^3)=(x,z^3)$. The radical of $(x,z^3)$
is $(x,z)$ so $P\supseteq(x,z)$. The ideal $(x,z)$ is the prime ideal you spotted; it's
not maximal, but any prime strictly containing it is.

If $z\in P$ then  $P\supseteq(z,xz,x^2y^2-z^3)=(x^2y^2,z)$. As $P$ is prime and
$x^2y^2\in P$ then either $x\in P$ or $y\in P$. The $x\in P$ case is dealt with,
the $y\in P$ case gives $P\supseteq(y,z)$ and the only such $P$ that isn't
maximal is $(y,z)$.

Comment: Thank you! But aren't there other prime ideal X which is not maximal and satisfies X⊃（x,z）? What you did doesn't seem to solve this problem t ,you  just found that ,all prime ideals, including I,should include (x,z) or (y,z).

Comment: @bellow Prime ideals containing $(x,z)$ correspond to prime ideals in the PID $\Bbb Q[x,y,z]/(x,z)=\Bbb Q[y]$.

Comment: If $P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x, y, z]$ such that $(x, z)\subsetneq P$,  then $P$ is maximal since $dim(\mathbb{Q}[x, y, z])=3$ and $0\subsetneq (x)\subsetneq(x, z)$ is a chain of prime ideals of length 2. Now as Angina Seng stated $(x, z)$ is the only prime (non-maximal) ideal of  $\mathbb{Q}[x, y, z]$ contianing $(x, z)$. Hence, $(x,z)/(x^2y^2-z^3)$ is the only prime  (non-maximal)  ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x, y, z]/(x^2y^2-z^3)$ contianing $(xz)/(x^2y^2-z^3)$.